# Understanding each_pair and map in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently reviewing some code and i would like to understand what this particular definition is trying to do.

```
def self.object_to_properties_container object
{
  'properties' => object.each_pair.map do |name, value|
    {'property' => name, 'value' => value}
  end
}
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked here? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will transform your Hash into another hash, which has one key: "properties" and this key contains another Hash of keys: "property" and "value", where "property" contains an original Hash key, and "value" - its value. Hard to elaborate, but easy with an example:

```
object_to_properties_container({ one: 1, two: 2})
#=> {"properties"=>
  [{"property"=>:one, "value"=>1}, {"property"=>:two, "value"=>2}]}
```

Comment: looks like `properties` contains an array of hashes